# Converting struct to constexpr array of uint8_t

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++17, constexpr

I need to create constexpr array of bytes out of constexpr struct.

```
#include <array>

template<typename T>
constexpr std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(T)> o2ba(const T o) {
    return {};
}

struct A {
    int a;
};

int main() {
    constexpr A x{ 1 };
    constexpr auto y = o2ba(x); // y == { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 } for little endian
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to extract it from union:

```
template<typename T>
union U {
    T o;
    std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(T)> d;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(T)> o2ba(const T o) {
    return U<T>{o}.d;
}
```

but it fails on both gcc and msvc compilers for accessing d instead of initialized o member. It works when initializing non constexpr object though, as below.

```
int main() {
    constexpr A x{ 1 };
    auto y = o2ba(x); // y == { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 } for little endian
    return 0;
}
```

But that is not what I need. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think this can be done. You either need to alias your variables using a union like you tried, or `reinterpret_cast` it to a different type. Both are not allowed in a `constexpr` context.

Comment: It is not possible. What should be possible is to write custom serialization functions for each type that you want to serialize. Such custom serialization function may try to produce an array that is as close to in-memory presentation as possible. Such function cannot be portable, so for each supported platform you will need different function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible. In your code, you try to access an initialized member in a `constexpr` context, which is fine. The error is that you then try to access a non-active member, which isn't permitted per [[expr.const#2.8]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#2.8):

> An expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of
>   e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of
>   the following expressions:
>
> ...
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that is applied to a glvalue that refers to a non-active member of a union or a subobject thereof;

Now the alternative is to try to serialize the object to bytes the old fashion way, via `reinterpret_cast`, i.e `reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&a)`. Again `reinterpret_cast`'s aren't allowed allowed in a `constexpr` context per 2.15 (same section). I suspect that the reason why you cannot do this is because it's unportable.