# C++17 - constexpr byte iteration for trivial types

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

Given my prototype for a simple hashing method:

```
template <typename _iterator>
constexpr uint32_t hash_impl(_iterator buf, size_t len);
```

Generating `constexpr` hashes for simple strings is pretty trivial:

```
template <char const* str>
constexpr uint32_t generate()
{
    constexpr std::string_view strView = str;
    return hash_impl(str, strView.size());
}
constexpr uint32_t generate(const std::string_view& str)
{
    return hash_impl(str.begin(), str.size());
}

constexpr static char str1[] = "Hello World!";
constexpr uint32_t hash1 = generate<str1>();

constexpr std::string_view str2("Hello World!");
constexpr uint32_t hash2 = generate(str2);
```

I'd also like to generate `constexpr` hashes for a variety of simple (POD and trivial structs) types too. However, I'm not sure how to get the byte representation of these types in a `constexpr`-friendly way.

My naive implementation:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_standard_layout_v<T> && !std::is_pointer_v<T> >>
constexpr uint32_t generate(const T& value)
{
    return hash_impl(reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(&value), sizeof(T));
}
```

falls over because `&value` and `reinterpret_cast<>` breaks constexpr rules. I've searched for a workaround, but other answers on the site indicate that it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111663/converting-struct-to-constexpr-array-of-uint8-t).

Worst case scenario, I can manually check for and hash specific types as so:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_standard_layout_v<T> && !std::is_pointer_v<T> >>
constexpr uint32_t generate(const T& value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int32_t> || std::is_same_v<T, uint32_t>)
    {
        char buf[] =
        {
            static_cast<char>(value >>  0),
            static_cast<char>(value >>  8),
            static_cast<char>(value >> 16),
            static_cast<char>(value >> 24)
        };
        return generate(buf, 4);
    }
    else if constexpr (/* etc... */)
    // ...
}
```

but this falls over as soon as I try to implement this for something like a float (which has no bitwise operators) or for trivial custom types (eg, `struct foo { int a; };` unless I write an extra code block for `foo`).

I feel like I must be overlooking something simple, but I can't find any stl utility or think of any fancy template trick that would suit. Perhaps there's something in C++20 or C++23 that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible in C++17. In C++20 you can use `std::bit_cast` to get the object representation of a trivially copyable type:

```
auto object_representation = std::bit_cast<std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T)>>(value);
```

(Technically you can argue about whether or not it is guaranteed that `std::array` has no additional padding/members that would make this ill-formed, but in practice that is not a concern.)

You can then pass the array as a pointer/size pair to the hash implementation. You should probably also add

```
static_assert(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<T>);
```

If the assertion fails you will have no guarantee that objects with same value will have the same object representation and same hash.

---

Btw. `std::is_standard_layout_v` is not the property you need here. The property that you need to verify is `std::is_trivially_copyable_v`. Being standard-layout is neither sufficient nor necessary to be able to inspect and use the object representation like this.

Comment: Great answer. re: std::is_standard_layout vs std::is_trivially_copyable, I'm not sure I agree in my use case. No copies are being made and types with deleted/inaccessible copy constructors should still be allowed. Standard layout already implies no virtual table ptr, no references, etc.

I suppose trivially copyable is more explicit about being convertable to bytes, but I really don't want to inherit the copy constructor behaviour. Is it a strict requirement of bit_cast?

Comment: @Salami If a type is not trivially copyable, then that means explicitly that the object representation does _not_ solely determine the value represented by the object, e.g. that there are embedded pointers which refer to additional memory relevant to the state. It is not necessary that the copy constructor is non-deleted. A non-deleted move constructor or copy/move assignment operator is sufficient, assuming the other ones are trivial (including deleted). This is a strict requirement for `std::bit_cast` and a necessary condition for copying object representation to be well-defined at all.

Comment: @Salami If the state represented by an object is determined completely by its object representation, then there would be no reason to delete copy/move operations or at least I don't see any point in that.  Accessibility doesn't matter by the way. Even if the trivial non-deleted copy/move operations are `private`, it is still trivially-copyable. On the other hand standard-layout has unnecessary restrictions like requiring all members to be declared in the same base class.

Comment: @Salami Also `std::has_unique_object_representations` is a refinement of `std::is_trivially_copyable` for that reason. It will naturally be `false` for non-trivially copyable types since there is no way to decide whether two object representations represent different states. (Think of `std::string` which may be standard-layout, but not trvially-copyable.)